# How do I change the value of hidden input dependent on what a person submits in another field of the same form?

Tags: php, html, forms

For example, if a user can submit red, yellow, or green on a form and I have hidden input that saying if user selects red the value of the hidden input is physco and if they select blue normal then finally if they select yellow the value is feminine.

I think this would be the same process as error checking but I'm not sure how to do this in html/php. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: if you need the hidden value to be dynamically updated based on the other field's value, you'd want to use javascript, not PHP. If you want to change the value of a database field (or field that gets emailed etc.) based on the value of the form input, then you can easily handle that using a simple [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement or if/then block in the form handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to change the value of a hidden form input, but this can be modified and/or JavaSript can be disabled.

If you are submitting the form to the server, you could assign this value server-side with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple javascript would suffice if the user is selecting a radiobutton from a group just add a function on the onclick event of the radiobutton and according to what the user has clicked change the value of the hidden field.